# How to approach a setInterval triggering a setInterval within the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I a rewards site. Users earn points when they watch videos. Users want to skip to the end of the video to quickly earn their points. Therefore, the mechanism of the video being marked as completed is managed by a JS timer.

**The Problem:** When a user pauses the video, the timer needs to pause. When the user clicks play again, a setInterval is used to reopen the function, where a setInterval within the existing function does the same thing, creating a *huge* problem...

*This is the code that is set every second to update the timer...*

```
var video_percent_count = 0;

function video_percent() {

  var prize_video = document.getElementById("prize_video");
  total_duration = Math.floor(prize_video.duration) + 1;

  video_percent_count++;
  percent = video_percent_count / total_duration;
  convert_percent = (percent * 100).toFixed(2);

  if(convert_percent == 100) {
    clearInterval(video_percent_interval);
  }

if(prize_video.paused) {
clearInterval(video_percent_interval);
}

if(prize_video.play) {
setInterval("video_percent()", 1000);
}

  $(".percent_container").text(convert_percent);
}

function prize_video(count_prize) {
    var back_count_prize = count_prize - 1;
    $("#prize_video").get(back_count_prize).play();
      video_percent_interval = setInterval("video_percent()", 1000);
}
```

**How can I properly manage *play* and *pause* and still keep `setInterval` clean?**

Comment: Do you have controls over the video?  Can't you just disable skipping forward in the video?

Comment: @karina I do have controls over the video. It almost seems unright to not allow user interaction with the video. What if the user misses part of the video and wants to rewatch it? Are users used to the idea of a video not being interactive?

Comment: I don't know... The internet seems pretty OK with gifs... And you are sorta punishing users for skipping forward so rather than punish why not just take away the option?  You can still give them a pause option

Comment: I though you need to remove setInterval from prize_video function, because once the video will get started to play it will definitely go in prize_video.play callback and set the interval for tracking percentage completion.

Comment: @karina has a point. Disable the fast forward control. Once the user has seen the video at least one time, you can enable the control.

Comment: You are checking a user's behavior with JavaScript. What happens if I am a JavaScript wizard and I change the code, allowing me to fast forward? Do you also have a server side security control?

Comment: @Enricov No, however, I'm pretty good at PHP. Would you mind giving an example on how I could provide server side protection?